# C++ Poco Epoch(Unix) time convert to LocalTime string

Tags: c++, datetime, poco, unix-timestamp, epoch

I have a string with Epoch(Unix) time.
Need to convert it to string with local time.
Code bellow works, but give me UTC time, not local.
**09-05-2017 21:55:44**

```
using Poco::Timestamp;
using Poco::DateTimeFormatter;

Timestamp timeStamp;
timeStamp = Timestamp::fromEpochTime(jrnTime);
timeFormatted = DateTimeFormatter::format(timeStamp, "%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S");
```

Comment: **%L** at the beginning converts to local

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Poco::LocalDateTime` which takes `Poco::DateTime` and `tzd` and convert to the local date time.

Answer (score -1):

Don't need to use Poco for this purpose.

```
#include <ctime>
using std::time_t;
using std::wstring;
using std::string;

string TimeStamp(time_t rawtime) {
    char buffer[80];
    struct tm timeinfo;
    localtime_s(&timeinfo, &rawtime);
    strftime(buffer, sizeof(buffer), "%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S", &timeinfo);
    return string(buffer);
}

wstring TimeStampW(time_t rawtime) {
    wchar_t buffer[80];
    struct tm timeinfo;
    localtime_s(&timeinfo, &rawtime);
    wcsftime(buffer, sizeof(buffer), L"%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S", &timeinfo);
    return wstring(buffer);
}
```